# jquery - right click not working

Tags: jquery, click

I Have the following test Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="..\Generic\JAVASCRIPT\jQuery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="..\Generic\JAVASCRIPT\jQuery-ui-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#SG1').click(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
})  
})

</script>

<p class="submit">
    <input id="SG1" type="submit" name="submit" value="SG1">
</p>
```

If I LEFT click, it works fine (event 1).

If I MIDDLE click, it works fine (event 2).

If I RIGHT click, nothing happens (well, I get the usual menu come up, but no alert)

If I change the action from `click` to `mousedown` it works as expected. Why wont it work with `click`? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: is it not because it's set up as default context menu by MS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the fact the the right click invokes the `contextmenu` event. If you want to disable that see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gk7zv9z/

In this fiddle when the contextmenu event is invoked the JS code prevents it from displaying the context menu and allows the programmer to do what ever he or she likes.

Comment: thanks for explaining it. That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to disable the contextmenu popup:

$("#SG1").bind("contextmenu", function () { return false; });

Then it should work.

Comment: Cheers for that, it's a useful bit of code to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Use mousedown

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xuv16dv2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#SG1').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
})  
})
```